# Using phpMyAdmin data as source for choropleth mapbox

Tags: maven, mapbox, choropleth

I'm working on a project where I need to show how many documents are invalid per department on my web site, which is display with Maven.
The problem is, I'm using phpmyadmin for my database, and I didn't find a way to use it as a source for the choropleth map. 
When I'm looking on Help topic on mapbox, there is only solutions with PostgreSQL and PostGIS.

The SQL request I need to use looks like this :

```
SELECT SUM(nbTransactionAnnule) FROM archivAnnule GROUP BY departement
```

I would like to know if someone have already had this problem, and how did you fix it?

Comment: You mean MySQL right? phpmyadmin is just a web interface for MySQL

Comment: Yes sorry, that's what I mean by phpmyadmin